# How to deploy PHP backend application by google cloud

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, angular5, ubuntu-18.04

I install in the google cloud app engine the Apache and PHP.
I put the files in var/www/html/.
I try to connect to PHP by POST, it's not working.
seem the PHP files no running.
Please help me! Thank!

Answer (score 0):

The way you use App Engine is by just deploying your applications, there is no need to install Apache or PHP on it. In fact there is a very simple guide over at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/quickstart which shows how to deploy a simple hello world application and you can start building from there.